# Flask and Flask SocketIO: receiving an event from inside of an external module

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I am developing an application to read some information from scientific instruments and displaying it using a remote web client. I am achieving this with Flask and Flask-SocketIO. I have a main `application.py` file which contains a Flask instance called `app`. I use this together with `Flask-SocketIO`. The HTML page deployed by Flask contains a Javascript Socketio instance which communicates with the server application (in python).

Besides, I have an external module which represents my scientific instrument. I want to receive events from the website (in Javascript) to this module-class. I tried passing the `app` and `socketio` python objects to the constructor in order to request the context from the Flask `app`. This works very well *only for emitting events from the module.*

In short, `application.py` has this basic structure:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
from flask import Flask, Response, render_template, session, request, g
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, disconnect, Namespace
from Instrument import *

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
socketio = SocketIO(app)

# some stuff here with @app.routes
@app.route('/instrument')
def inst(arg):
    t = Instrument(arg, app, socketio)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, port=8000, log_output=True)
```

For the external module `Instrument.py` I tried to use the decorator syntax unsuccessfully (kind of `@self.socketio.on`, I am not so acquainted with them). So I tried with the following code:

```
class Instrument():
    def __init__(self, arg, app, socketio):
        self.app = app
        self.socketio = socketio
        self.socketio.on_event('someCoolEvent', self.someCoolMethod, namespace='/coolapp') # THIS GIVES ME ERRORS

    def someCoolMethod():
        with self.app.test_request_context('/coolapp'):
            self.socketio.emit('emittedEvent', namespace='/telescope') # THIS WORKS FINE
```

The error I am getting is the following (EDITED: added two lines that can be useful):

```
[2017-03-03 06:31:31,456][INFO] - _handle_event: received event "my event" from a40724e9e60e4a61ace9e19e59ceabda [/telescope]
[2017-03-03 06:31:31,604][INFO] - handle_get_request: a40724e9e60e4a61ace9e19e59ceabda: Received request to upgrade to websocket
[2017-03-03 06:31:33 +0000] [6333] [ERROR] Error handling request /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=24e7d134ea4c4840888c28e0e3ff1f6d
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/instr_gui/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/async.py", line 52, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener_name, req, client, addr)
  File "/home/user/instr_gui/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 152, in handle_request
    super(GeventWorker, self).handle_request(*args)
  File "/home/user/instr_gui/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/async.py", line 103, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/home/user/instr_gui/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1994, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/user/instr_gui/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 42, in __call__
    start_response)
  File "/home/user/instr_gui/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/engineio/middleware.py", line 47, in __call__
    return self.engineio_app.handle_request(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/user/instr_gui/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/socketio/server.py", line 353, in handle_request
    return self.eio.handle_request(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/user/instr_gui/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/engineio/server.py", line 260, in handle_request
    environ, start_response)
  File "/home/user/instr_gui/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/engineio/socket.py", line 86, in handle_get_request
    start_response)
  File "/home/user/instr_gui/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/engineio/socket.py", line 127, in _upgrade_websocket
    return ws(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/user/instr_gui/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/engineio/async_gevent.py", line 34, in __call__
    raise RuntimeError('You need to use the gevent-websocket server. '
RuntimeError: You need to use the gevent-websocket server. See the Deployment section of the documentation for more information.
```

When the app is initialised, the log says:

```
2017-03-04 02:52:04 [23530] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
2017-03-04 02:52:04 [23530] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (23530)
2017-03-04 02:52:04 [23530] [INFO] Using worker: gevent
2017-03-04 02:52:04 [23534] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 23534
```

So I have tried configuring the file `/etc/init/myapp.conf` with both `gunicorn -k gevent -w 1 module:app` and `gunicorn -k geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker -w 1 module:app` but I'm getting the same error.

At the browser I see another error, that appears at the same time as the 'main' one:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://somewebpage.com:2080/socket.io/?
EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=572923d1b8fd402795bba50823941520' 
failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500
```

How can I receive events correctly from the external module? Maybe there is a better way to achieve the result I want. I would be very grateful if someone gives me a hand with this.

Comment: I find it really odd that gunicorn reports `Using worker: gevent` when you added the `-k geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker` option to the start up lline. That really makes no sense, you are telling it to use a different worker. I think you need to confirm that, because the error that you are getting is directly related to not using the gevent-websocket worker.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain so clear. I verified it and it behaves as you said (normal). Now I just changed the nginx configuration file as described in this post [Error during WebSocket handshake](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1942) and I'm not getting the exception I described. So, your theory was right :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer myself. I found the [following post](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1942), which explains that the error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://somewebpage.com:2080/socket.io/?
EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=572923d1b8fd402795bba50823941520' 
failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500
```

is caused due to a misconfiguration in the nginx configuration file. It should be like this:

```
...
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";

    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
}
...
```

Now works like a charm: emitting and receiving events, from the imported module and from the main python script.

Answer (score 0):

can you try add `policy_server=False` in `socketio.run(app, port=8000, log_output=True,policy_server=False)`

Comment: Thanks, but I got the same result.

Comment: So the problem is with server , have you try using gunicorn webserver : https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#gunicorn-web-server

Comment: But how can the server be the problem if `emit`, `connect` and `disconnect` in the python script work fine?

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting is unrelated to your problem, I think. It's saying that you are using the standard gunicorn worker for gevent, but you need to use the gevent-websocket worker for websocket to work. See the last example in this [section](http://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#gunicorn-web-server) of the documentation.

Comment: Thanks. I added more information to my question. I don't think it's related to that, since I have tried with both `gevent` and `gevent-websocket`. The strangest thing is that my python app can send events correctly (with data) to the browser, but there seems to be a problem recognising them the way around. In the python app's log I see messages like `[2017-03-04 03:01:50,847][INFO] - receive: 57...1520: Received packet MESSAGE data 2/telescope,["RandomEvent"]
[2017-03-04 03:01:50,847][INFO] - _handle_event: received event "RandomEvent" from 5729...1520 [/coolapp]` after the exception.